# How to filter export data based on value-matching in another sheet and AND OR filters

Tags: excel

I have `Sheet1` `Sheet2`.

EG, in `Sheet1` I have

```
|Column A|Column B|Column C|Column D|Column E|Column F|Column G|
|1001    |Step 1  |ID1     |---     |---     |---     |---     |
|1002    |Step 2  |ID2     |        |        |        |        |
|1003    |Step 3  |ID3     |        |        |        |        |
```

In `Sheet2` I have

```
|Column A|
|ID1     |
|ID2     |
|ID3     |
```

I need to export all values from `Sheet1` where the values in Column C matches values in Column A in `Sheet2`, and also filtering out a set of values in Column A. In Column A, there are six different values that must match individually, but also two values that must match together, EG 1001 OR 1002 OR (1001 AND 1003).

All values matching those criterias should then be exported to another sheet, and if possible, insert a certain value in Column E (same value in all rows).

Is this possible, and how? Also, if my question is unclear, I'll try to specify what I mean in a better way.

Comment: You should be able to devise an `Advanced Filter` to do this. Your downvotes and close votes are because this is not a free code-writing service. It is here help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld, thanks for the message. I'm sorry for making it seem like I wanted someone to write the code for me. I managed to find a solution myself, and will post the answer here in case somebody else wonders at a later time.

Comment: You may even be able to mark your response as the Answer (or you might need some more points to do that, I can't recall).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks again - I can do it in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved this:
=+VLOOKUP(C1;'Sheet2'!A:C;2;FALSE) - to check that the IDs in Sheet1 Column C matches IDs in Sheet2 Column A.
Another VLOOKUP for the values in Column A - I made another sheet with the values that had to match these.
I also made a Pivot table to crosscheck the data.